# Writing a "telnet server" type program that uses SSH instead of telnet

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, telnet

So people have written server programs using telnet in which the user simply does `telnet server.com` and this connects them to the server program, which then provides them with a textual program they can use over the net (like a MUD). There are some here, for example:

http://www.telnet.org/htm/places.htm

I wanted to write a server program like that, but I want it to have security against evesdropping and MITM attacks that SSH offers. So is it possible to write a program in which the user can do this on a linux machine `ssh server.com` or maybe this `ssh guest@server.com` and be patched into a similar text program as these telnet servers?

Answer (score 6):

Create a user and set his login shell to your command.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install sl
sudo adduser foo
sudo chsh -s $(which sl) foo
ssh foo@localhost
```

[image]

Also have a look at `man sshd_config` for some other ways to configure you ssh server. (Like adding a `ForceCommand`.)

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I'm looking for. Follow up question - If i do this, I'm going to have a program that is accessed by many people simultaneously over the net, each running their own instance of the program. If have them all log in as the one user ( guest@server.com ), will they be able to evesdrop on other connections to guest@server.com using packet sniffers or other such tools?

Comment: No, they wont. Each user has his own TCP/SSH connection. The kernel will make sure that network packages for one connection are only send to the corresponding client. However you should  write your configured server command very carefully. If your server allows users to open some kind of shell they have lots of possibilities. (But that is common to all kind of server applications.)

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh user@server telnet localhost 1234
```